# add a `new Audio` element to my redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I am trying to add a `new Audio` element to my redux store.

I have a reducer that looks like this:

```
export const songsReducer = (state = {}, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {
        case "PLAY_SONG":
           return {
             ...state,
             songPlaying: true,
             songDetails: action.song,
             audioPlaying: new Audio(action.song.url)
        }


        case "STOP_SONG":
            return {
              ...state,
              songPlaying: false,
              songDetails: null
            }

        default:
          return state;
    }

};

export default songsReducer;
```

However, when I check my redux store `audioPlaying` is an empty object like this `{}`

Can anyone advise what I am doing wrong here?

the component where I call the action is here

```
class Audio extends Component {

    static audio;

    playSong = (song) => {
        if(!this.props.audioPlaying){
            this.props.playSong(song);
            // I want to move the following lines out of the 
            // component as I need to control the audio from elsewhere in the app 
            // this.audio = new Audio(song.url); 
            // this.audio.play(); 
        } else {
            this.props.songsReducer.audio.pause();
            this.props.playSong(song);
            // this.audio = new Audio(song.url);
            // this.audio.play();
        }
    }

    render() {
       this.props.songs.map(song => {
         return (
           <li onClick={(song) => this.playSong(song)}>Play { song.name }</li>
         );
      });
    }
};
```

Comment: post the component where you trigger PLAY_SONG action

Comment: @Karim added the relevant code

Comment: did you check with the debugger if it reaches the PLAY_SONG case in the reducer? please add the mapdispatch and mapstate functions

Comment: it does reach it, I can see in the chrome dev tools

Answer (score 1):

What is the `Audio` object?

Otherwise I would suggest to store the playing song directly in the property `audioPlaying`. I assume `action.song.url` is a string for the song url.

Instead of doing this:

```
audioPlaying: new Audio(action.song.url)
```

Do this:

```
audioPlaying: action.song.url
```

As I can see your redux state is not immutable, that might cause you some issues later on. I would suggest you to use a library like [Immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) to solve that.

Comment: @peter-flanagan Are you trying to store your React component ?